# How to create multiple primary keys in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have to create a Composite Primary key. I have three columns of type string.
I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704436/creating-a-composition-primary-key-using-scala-slick)

```
def a = Column[String]("a")
def b = Column[String]("b")
def c = Column[String]("c")

def pk = primaryKey("pk_notifications", (a,b,c))
```

But there is no primary key when i describe the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using SqlType could be one of the options

```
def a = Column[String]("a", SqlType("varchar(50)"))
def b = Column[String]("b", SqlType("varchar(50)"))
def c = Column[String]("c", SqlType("varchar(50)"))

def pk = primaryKey("pk_notifications", (a,b,c))
```